# Filtering output using an array of column names in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have specific column names saved in an array, but if I pipe Select $columnarray, it treats the entire array as a string (1 column).

```
$columnarray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$columnarray.add("fname")
$columnarray.add("lname")
$columnarray.add("pc")
$columnarray = $columnarray -join ','
Import-Csv "C:/temp/test.csv" | ?{$_.'fname' -eq "john"} | Select $columnarray
```

Is it possible to get this working?

Comment: It treats it as a string because you make it a string. Remove `$columnarray = $columnarray -join ','` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TessellatingHeckler for pointing out that
    $columnarray = $columnarray -join ','
was making the array into a string. I have removed this line and it works perfectly.